# How to control legend with many groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a plot like this:

[image]

Which was created with this code:

```
# Make data:
set.seed(42)
n <- 1000
df <- data.frame(values = sample(0:5, size = n, replace = T, prob = c(9/10,  rep(0.0167,5))), 
                 group  = rep(1:100, each = 10), 
                 fill2  = rep(rnorm(10), each = 100),
                 year   = rep(2001:2010, times = 100)
                 )
df$values <- ifelse(df$year %in% 2001:2007 == T, 0, df$values)

# Plot
require(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = year, y = values, colour = as.factor(group))) + geom_line()
p
```

Since there are so many groups, the legend is really not helpfull. 
Ideally I would like just two elements in the legend, one for group = 1 and for all the other groups (they should all have the same color). Is there a way to force this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define a new variable that has only two values, but still plot lines according to their original group,

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = year, y = values, group = group,
                      colour = ifelse(group == 1, "1", "!1"))) +  
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_brewer("groups", palette="Set1")
```